# Docker image does not work on AWS Fargate but it does in EC2

Tags: php, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm changing infrastructure on AWS and I want to use Docker (ECS) with Fargate. My Docker image is based on Ubuntu and I install all I need in it. I'm using Laravel 5.6 on NGINX running PHP 7.2. My Docker container works on my local machine and if I run ECS with EC2, however when I change to Fargate it returns NGINX 500 error. I did some tests and I know PHP is running, only when I install my Laravel app the error happens.

Since I cannot access Fargate machine I don't know how to debug. I tryied to connect NGINX with Loggly however it requires rsyslog and since I'm using Docker it cannot access Ubuntu's core. When I install and try to run it returns:

```
rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV BACKEND_PATH=/code/Backend
ENV FRONTEND_PATH=/code/Frontend

## Update
RUN apt-get update -y

## Upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:certbot/certbot
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get dist-upgrade -y
RUN apt-get autoremove -y
RUN apt-get update -y

## Nano
RUN apt-get install -y nano

## Timezone
RUN echo "America/Sao_Paulo" > /etc/timezone && \
    apt-get install -y tzdata && \
    rm /etc/localtime && \
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata && \
    apt-get clean

## Git
RUN apt-get install -y git

## NGINX
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
COPY ./nginx/app/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-available
COPY ./nginx/app/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
COPY ./nginx/sites /etc/nginx/sites
COPY ./nginx/ssl /ssl

## PHP
RUN apt-get install -y php-cli php-fpm php-curl php-mbstring
COPY ./php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install libs
RUN apt-get install -y php-zip php-mysql php-gd pngquant gifsicle jpegoptim libicu-dev g++ php-intl php-xml

## Crontab
RUN apt-get install -y cron
COPY crontab newcrontab
RUN crontab newcrontab
RUN rm newcrontab

## Supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
COPY ./supervisord /etc/supervisor/conf.d

## Certbot
RUN apt-get install -y python-certbot-nginx

## Install apps
COPY ./code/Backend /code/Backend
COPY ./code/Frontend/dist /code/Frontend/dist

RUN cd ${BACKEND_PATH} && chmod +x composer.phar && ./composer.phar self-update && php composer.phar install
RUN chmod -Rf 777 ${BACKEND_PATH}/storage
RUN chmod -Rf 777 ${BACKEND_PATH}/resources
RUN php ${BACKEND_PATH}/artisan config:clear
RUN php ${BACKEND_PATH}/artisan passport:keys

## Run!
EXPOSE 80 443

RUN service php7.2-fpm start
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

I think this error has something to do with permissions but without error message it's almost impossible to know what's going on... Does anyone have any ideia how I may find this out?

Comment: Can you include your Dockerfile? If you are using an entrypoint script that would be helpful as well.

Comment: @bluescores I just added the Dockerfile

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but something for your Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers

Comment: You can run an ssh server in a Fargate container. [Docker has a tutorial on running sshd in a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/#build-an-eg_sshd-image), with Fargate just make sure you can access the container on port 22 or whatever custom port you configure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Really stupid mistake actually. When I created Fargate configurations I used a Security Group without permissions to access some AWS components so the application was unable to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/691048/kernel-log-stays-empty-rsyslogd-imklog-cannot-open-kernel-log-proc-kmsg

Try running the Fargate task with the `--privileged` flag. You can set this flag in the AWS console per-container in the task definition. It's in the SECURITY section near the end of the container definition. [Here's the full reference for container definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definitions).

Comment: Thank you! Is this flag available on `docker build`? I have this error when I build the image.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Fargate has nothing to do with building an image, your image would be built if you're trying to deploy it to Fargate. "My Docker container works on my local machine and if I run ECS with EC2", yet you're getting the error with `docker build` ?

Comment: There is the main error when I run on Fargate (error 500 that does not happen when I run on EC2). So to debug I tried to link Loggly, but when I run `docker build` this "rsyslogd" error happens. Originally I didn't try to link with Loggly, I just did that to debug NGINX in Fargate.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I would suggest editing your question to clarify, and also be mindful of only asking only one question. It sounds like the `/proc/kmesg` error was part of your debugging efforts, which is useful information, but ultimately not the question you want answered.

Comment: You're right, it isn't clear. Thank you for your help and tips.